# How to Improve a string related iterator performance?

Tags: c++, optimization

I made an iterator that reads lines from an `istream<string>` instance and converts them to `vector<pair<string, string> >`'s. Can I optimize this to perform better by reducing string copies (or anything else for that matter)?

Here's a summary of the code, but I've also got a [full version with a few simple tests and a `makefile`](https://gist.github.com/aaronj1335/11327697).

```
typedef std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string> > sentence;

class my_iterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, sentence> {
  std::istream* is;
  std::string line;
  sentence s;

  void advance() {
    std::getline(*is, line);
    convert();
  }

  void convert() {
    std::istringstream iss(line);

    s.clear();

    for (std::istream_iterator<std::string> it(iss), end; it != end; ++it) {

      std::string token = *it;
      size_t idx = token.find_last_of('/');
      std::string word = token.substr(0, idx);
      std::string part_of_speech = token.substr(idx, token.size());

      s.push_back(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(word, part_of_speech));
    }
  }

  public:
    my_iterator& operator++() {
      assert(is && !is->eof());

      if (is && !is->eof())
        advance();

      if (is->eof())
        is = NULL;

      return *this;
    }

    sentence operator*() const {
      return s;
    }

    const sentence* operator->() const {
      return &s;
    }

    bool operator==(const my_iterator& rhs) const {
      return is == rhs.is;
    }

    /* some more boilerplate constructors, etc */
};
```

The input looks something like this:

```
Mr./NNP Vinken/NNP is/VBZ chairman/NN of/IN Elsevier/NNP N.V./NNP ,/, the/DT Dutch/NNP publishing/VBG group/NN ./.
There/EX is/VBZ no/DT asbestos/NN in/IN our/PRP$ products/NNS now/RB ./. ''/''
```

Comment: For starters it is wrong. Generally the stream won't have `eof()` set after reading the last line as it just stopped with extracting the last character (the newline) wihtout hitting newline. That is, the end isn't properly detected. To improve performance you should _not_ construct an `std::istringstream` each time but rather keep it around and reaset it if you insist in using a string stream internally (I wouldn't; I would parse the values immediately off the original stream). You should also consider moving the temporary string when `push_back()`ing them.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions! (1) how do i detect an empty istream w/o eof? (2) do i "reset" the `istringstream` w/ `iss.str()`? (3) when you say "moving the temporary string", do you just mean making `line` a local var to the convert fn?

Comment: 1. You'll need to move the stream to a readable character before determining whether it has reached `eof()`. I think, using `(in >> std::ws).eof()` for the condition should do the trick. 2. yes, you can use the `str()` member. 3. I mean you would either use `std::move(x)` for the local variable `x`. If you don't use C++11 you could avoid a copy by not assigning the values to a local variable but immediately using them when adding to the vector. Alternatively, you could could push an empty element and set its members.

Answer (score 1):

A few observations:

1. It does not really matter whether it reads the file line by line or word by word, because you only process it by word. So read it word by word with `for(std::string word; std::cin >> word; ) ...`
2. Each word has a form of `word/part_of_speach`. If you break `word/part_of_speach` into two `std::string` objects that takes more space because each string stores a size and a zero terminator. You can split `word/part_of_speach` on demand only when needed or store the position of last `/` in that string like `std::pair<std::string, size_t>`.

E.g.:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <boost/iterator/transform_iterator.hpp>

int main() {
    // Store word/part_of_speach tokens.
    std::vector<std::string> tokens(
          std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin)
        , std::istream_iterator<std::string>()
        );

    // Now process them as word and part_of_speach.
    auto break_token = [](std::string const& token) { return std::make_pair(&token, token.find_last_of('/')); };
    std::for_each(
          boost::make_transform_iterator(tokens.begin(), break_token)
        , boost::make_transform_iterator(tokens.end(), break_token)
        , [](std::pair<std::string const*, size_t> const& broken_token) {
              (std::cout << "word: ").write(broken_token.first->data(), broken_token.second);
              std::cout << " part_of_speach: " << broken_token.first->data() + broken_token.second;
              std::cout << '\n';
          }
        );
}
```

Outputs:

```
$ echo -e "Mr./NNP Vinken/NNP is/VBZ chairman/NN of/IN Elsevier/NNP N.V./NNP ,/, the/DT Dutch/NNP publishing/VBG group/NN ./. There/EX is/VBZ no/DT asbestos/NN in/IN our/PRP$ products/NNS now/RB ./. ''/''" | ./test
word: Mr. part_of_speach: /NNP
word: Vinken part_of_speach: /NNP
word: is part_of_speach: /VBZ
word: chairman part_of_speach: /NN
word: of part_of_speach: /IN
word: Elsevier part_of_speach: /NNP
word: N.V. part_of_speach: /NNP
word: , part_of_speach: /,
word: the part_of_speach: /DT
word: Dutch part_of_speach: /NNP
word: publishing part_of_speach: /VBG
word: group part_of_speach: /NN
word: . part_of_speach: /.
word: There part_of_speach: /EX
word: is part_of_speach: /VBZ
word: no part_of_speach: /DT
word: asbestos part_of_speach: /NN
word: in part_of_speach: /IN
word: our part_of_speach: /PRP$
word: products part_of_speach: /NNS
word: now part_of_speach: /RB
word: . part_of_speach: /.
word: '' part_of_speach: /''
```

Answer (score 0):

You push strings to a vector - now while this isn't particularly bad, once you reach the end of the currently-allocated size of the vector, it will get resized for you. This can be a performance hit. One that is easily solved by pre-sizing your vector (if you know how many words will be present), or using a different collection such as a queue.

the other thing you can try is to reduce temporaries - you copy the data from *it into a string and then tokenise it, you could reduce this copy by operating directly on the stream data - though you'll need a different routine to read the tokens.

Pushing onto the vector will also copy the string, you could use a unique_ptr<> to hold these instead so you use a single string, or construct the first inside the vector and work on it instead.

Comment: `unique_ptr` would complicate the code, it's easier just to use `std::move` to transfer the strings into the vector, and use emplace to avoid a temporary pair. `s.emplace_back(std::move(word), std::move(part_of_speech));`

Comment: @JonathanWakely fair enough, but some people still don't get to use C++11 :-(

Comment: There is no `boost::unique_ptr` (although there is a `boost::interprocess::unique_ptr` used as an implementation detail of Boost.Interprocess)